# Upgrade to 1.9.2.1 caused duplicate transactions in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, transaction, magento-1.9.2.1, duplicate

After digging through and analyzing the data being sent from Magento to Google Analytics (GA), it seems that after the 1.9.2.1 update was applied to the site, Magento began sending successful transactions in duplicate to GA.

Analyzing a "Duplicate Transactions" report in GA, there's a clear transaction where it goes from 1 transaction sent / order to 2. Tracking that order number and comparing it to the commit history in the repo, the only update made to the code base on that date was the launch of the new version 1.9.2.1.

The code is properly implemented in the *success.phtml* page as expected, and runs the GA Universal Tracking code. There are other conversion code snippets on the page, they all show a duplication after the date in question.

Has anyone else experienced this? Anyone have any idea as to why this would be happening or a solution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I've never seen this before but first thought is if you have any 3rd party or google analytics extensions installed remove them. Then I would check both the header and footer misc scripts to ensure there isn't additional tracking code inserted there.

Comment: Thanks Erik, no additional GA third party extensions, all we have is the Magento GA enabled (Google API). I also checked the header and template files, and no duplication there. Checking the source code, all that is seen is the Magento generated GA code. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

We have experience this issue after upgrading our Magento EE to 1.14.2.2. So it was doubling the order value at GA and also affected many other measurements at GA.

Then we disable all GA related Magento modules (Enterprise_GoogleAnalyticsUniversal, Mage_GoogleAnalytics, Mage_GoogleCheckout) by going to System > Configuration > Advanced.

That actually FIXED the issue. Since we do not use any Magento GA plugins we kept them disabled. Now all our GA reporting coming through correctly.

I'm not sure if this is an option for you. But this answer may help any other who gets a similar issue.